# Stackoverflow-like questions/answer functionality for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Does anyone know of a solution that provides functionality to Microsoft Sharepoint that offers Stackoverflow like functionality?

Answer (score 3):

I would really recommend not using SharePoint for this kind of feature.  SharePoint is great at what it does (document management, collaboration, etc) but absolutely terrible at everything else.

Are you forced to develop for SharePoint, or can you just do it in ASP.NET/C#?

Comment: we have a share point environment available and wanted to investigate potential uses.  I tend to agree that a stand-alone product is probably better.

Comment: @Matthew Jones, I agree that out the box SharePoint is very document-centric but it's also incredibly flexible and can be turned to most purposes. The problem usually comes down to the incredibly steep learning curve and cumbersome development cycle (IISReset anyone?). However, if there's a strong requirement for integrating your application into a large windows network environment with tight control over permissions and workflow then it's second to none. Add a few additional elements in such as Nintex workflow and Newsgator social sites then it can be an incredibly powerful enterprise tool.

Answer (score 2):

Any SharePoint functionality that did with would most likely be completely custom ASP.NET pages that would run just as well as a stand-alone product.

Rather than looking for a SharePoint-specific product, look for one that works well with the general microsoft stack, and you should be able to integrate it fairly well with whatever SharePoint site you're running.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using [StackExchange](http://www.stackexchange.com/) (either hosted or local for a price!) when it becomes available in September(ish), but that is probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Idea Center feature](http://www.newsgator.com/solutions/innovation-management.aspx) in Newsgator Social Sites, check the [screenshot](http://www.newsgator.com/images/screenshot_ideas3.jpg). I haven't used this although our company is trialling this product so I hope to have a look at it soon.

The downsides are that this is part of a much bigger (albeit pretty cool) product and isn't free.

Answer (score 0):

There are some elements of answers on the Sharepoint stack exchange:

- Do it yourself

  - Custom content types
  - Upgrade the discussion forum
- With commercial software

  - Use Lighting tools solutions http://lightningtools.com/
  - Use Bamboo solutions https://store.bamboosolutions.com/pfi-211-discussion-board-plus-for-sharepoint.aspx

(Original link: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20321/sharepoint-qa-tool-like-stack-exchange)

Technically speaking, Sharepoint may not be the most optimal platform to do this. However, if your entreprise architecture already has the framework, and your users know the platform, it is not completely irrelevant to try that way. Some benefits I see:

- Benefits from the standard Sharepoint search results
- Easier to get employees opt-in